# Python How can i create a class from a list derived from a txt file?

Tags: python, list, class

I have a txt file with 2 lines of text. I want each row of this text file to become a class. i have made each row into a list, and i want each element of that list to become a part of a class.

My text file looks like this.

VardagsrumsTV/Pengar är inte allt/Svt 1/4
KöksTv/Music is life/TV3/1

I have another file thats supposed to read this file and create a class for each row. That program looks like this.

```
class TV_apparat(object):
    def __init__(self, name, program, kanal, volym):
        self.name=name
        self.program=program
        self.kanal=kanal
        self.volym=volym
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s: \n Tv-program: %s \n Kanal: %s \n Ljudvolymen: %s " % (self.name, self.program, self.kanal,self.volym)

filename=open("TVinfo.txt", "r")
Tvinfo=filename.read()
filename.close()
Tvinfo = [line.split("/") for line in Tvinfo.split("\n")]

print (Tvinfo)
tvList=[]
for rad in Tvinfo:
    tvList.append(TV_apparat(rad[0],rad[1],rad[2],int(rad[3])))
    break

TVclasses = dict([(TV, TV_apparat(name)) for TVs in tvList])
print (TVclasses)
```

What i want is each row to become a class object of TV_apparat.

So i want one class called VardagsrumsTV with name=VardagsrumsTV, program=Pengar är inte allt, kanal=Svt 1 and volym=4
and one class with name=KöksTv, program=Music is life, kanal=TV3 and volym=1

What i get out from this is this so far 
[['VardagsrumsTV', 'Pengar Ã¤r inte allt', 'Svt 1', '4'], ['KÃ¶ksTv', 'Music is life', 'TV3', '1'], ['']]

(UTF-8 isnt working very well with these swedish letters)

What can i do to get classes shaped like i want them?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to move the line parsing logic inside the `__init__()` method.

Here an example:

```
class TV_apparat(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.name, self.program, self.kanal, self.volym = line.strip().split("/")
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s: \n Tv-program: %s \n Kanal: %s \n Ljudvolymen: %s " % (self.name, self.program, self.kanal,self.volym)


filename = "TVinfo.txt"
tvList=[]
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('\n'):
            tvList.append(TV_apparat(line))
```